# PDFView in modalwindow

Tags: objective-c, modal-dialog, pdfview

I have a Cocoa application that opens a modal window, that loads loads a pdf from a ftp server, and displays it in a PDFView. I use ARC

```
    PDFViewerWindowController *pdfViewerWindowController = [[PDFViewerWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"PDFViewerWindow"];
    [pdfViewerWindowController setDocumentForUrl:url];
    [NSApp runModalForWindow:[pdfViewerWindowController window]];
```

and here is the setDocumentForUrl:

```
-(void)setDocumentForUrl:(NSString *)url
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ftp://192.168.32.11%@", url];
    pdfDoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [pdfView setDocument: pdfDoc];
}
```

I get this error (this does not happen all the times):

```
Crashed Thread:  4

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000d, 0x0000000000000000



Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff95626e90 objc_msgSend + 16
1   com.apple.PDFKit                0x00007fff972fadfc -[PDFView dealloc] + 48
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff96d66401 -[NSConcreteNotification dealloc] + 61
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8edf3ab0 CFRelease + 176
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ee1bf90 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 304
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff96ddace3 -[NSNotificationQueue _flushNotificationQueue] + 84
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff96ddac51 -[NSNotificationQueue dealloc] + 27
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8edf3ab0 CFRelease + 176
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ee5c8a7 CFRunLoopObserverInvalidate + 295
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ee5cc14 __CFRunLoopObserverDeallocate + 20
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8edf3bf6 CFRelease + 502
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ee5915b __CFRunLoopDeallocateObservers + 235
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8edfd2d2 __CFSetApplyFunction_block_invoke_1 + 18
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8edfd121 CFBasicHashApply + 113
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8edfd0a4 CFSetApplyFunction + 212
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ee58c0f __CFRunLoopDeallocate + 127
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8edf3bf6 CFRelease + 502
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ee36c80 __CFTSDFinalize + 96
18  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff94b1e942 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 230
19  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff94ad9f7c _pthread_exit + 142
20  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff94ada59e _pthread_wqthread + 768
21  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff94adbb85 start_wqthread + 13
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated, 
Radu

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible to use a PDFView in a modal window. Does it work if you use the same code in a normal window?

Comment: It works on Snow Leopard with no problem, but it doesn't work all the time on Lion (I only get this error some times)